# Как выводить полученную после парсинга информацию в красивом виде? Python

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

Как изменить вывод информации, что записывается в info, чтобы полученная информация выводилась в столбик, например?

```
def getcontent(html):
    soup = BS(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='account-row')
    accinfo = soup.find_all('div', class_='account-steaminfo-row')
    faccinfo = soup.find_all('div', class_='account-faceit-stats-single')

    for item in items:
        info.append(
            {
                'name': item.find('div', class_='account-steam-name').get_text(strip=True),
                'faceitname': item.find('div', class_='account-faceit-title').find('span').get_text(),
                'link': item.find('div', class_='account-steam-userpic').find("a").get("href"),
                'avatar': item.find('div', class_='account-steam-userpic').find('img').get("src"),
                'trust': item.find('div', class_='account-steam-trust').get("title"),
                'registerdate': accinfo[1].get_text(strip=False).replace('', ''),
                'firstcs': accinfo[2].get_text(strip=False).replace('', ''),
                'cshours': accinfo[3].get_text(strip=False).replace('', ''),
                'lastweekhours': accinfo[4].get_text(strip=False).replace('', ''),
                'achhack': accinfo[5].get_text(strip=False).replace('', ''),
                'matches': faccinfo[0].get_text(strip=False).replace('', ''),
                'elo': faccinfo[1].get_text(strip=False).replace('', ''),
                'kd': faccinfo[2].get_text(strip=False).replace('', '')
            }
        )
    return info


def pars():
    html = gethtml(ffurl)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        print(getcontent(html.text))
    else:
        print("-")
```

**Вывод:**

```latex
[{'name': 'mouse.', 'faceitname': 'ya_lublu_sir', 'link': 'https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561199093445177', 'avatar': 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/87/8795cc1582c0949615b54bdac3c3c1f7267ec089_full.jpg', 'trust': 'Уровень доверия = 0%', 'registerdate': 'Аккаунт создан: 25.09.2020', 'firstcs': 'Играет в CS:GO с: 25.09.2020', 'cshours': 'Всего часов в CS:GO: 1080.2', 'lastweekhours': 'Часов CS:GO за 2 недели: 6.3', 'achhack': 'Достижения CS:GO: Не взломаны', 'matches': 'Матчей: 36', 'elo': 'ELO: 790', 'kd': 'K/D: 1.32'}]
```

Comment: Используйте `pprint` для json (словарь) или `soup.prettify()` для html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from pprint import pprint

a = [{'name': 'mouse.', 'faceitname': 'ya_lublu_sir', 'link': 'https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561199093445177', 'avatar': 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/87/8795cc1582c0949615b54bdac3c3c1f7267ec089_full.jpg', 'trust': 'Уровень доверия = 0%', 'registerdate': 'Аккаунт создан: 25.09.2020', 'firstcs': 'Играет в CS:GO с: 25.09.2020', 'cshours': 'Всего часов в CS:GO: 1080.2', 'lastweekhours': 'Часов CS:GO за 2 недели: 6.3', 'achhack': 'Достижения CS:GO: Не взломаны', 'matches': 'Матчей: 36', 'elo': 'ELO: 790', 'kd': 'K/D: 1.32'}]
pprint(a, sort_dicts=False)
```

output:

```latex
[{'name': 'mouse.',
  'faceitname': 'ya_lublu_sir',
  'link': 'https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561199093445177',
  'avatar': 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/87/8795cc1582c0949615b54bdac3c3c1f7267ec089_full.jpg',
  'trust': 'Уровень доверия = 0%',
  'registerdate': 'Аккаунт создан: 25.09.2020',
  'firstcs': 'Играет в CS:GO с: 25.09.2020',
  'cshours': 'Всего часов в CS:GO: 1080.2',
  'lastweekhours': 'Часов CS:GO за 2 недели: 6.3',
  'achhack': 'Достижения CS:GO: Не взломаны',
  'matches': 'Матчей: 36',
  'elo': 'ELO: 790',
  'kd': 'K/D: 1.32'}]
```

Или

```py
a = [{'name': 'mouse.', 'faceitname': 'ya_lublu_sir', 'link': 'https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561199093445177',
      'avatar': 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/87/8795cc1582c0949615b54bdac3c3c1f7267ec089_full.jpg',
      'trust': 'Уровень доверия = 0%', 'registerdate': 'Аккаунт создан: 25.09.2020',
      'firstcs': 'Играет в CS:GO с: 25.09.2020', 'cshours': 'Всего часов в CS:GO: 1080.2',
      'lastweekhours': 'Часов CS:GO за 2 недели: 6.3', 'achhack': 'Достижения CS:GO: Не взломаны',
      'matches': 'Матчей: 36', 'elo': 'ELO: 790', 'kd': 'K/D: 1.32'}]
print(*[f'{k} => {v}' for elem in a for k, v in elem.items()], sep='\n')
```

output

```latex
name => mouse.
faceitname => ya_lublu_sir
link => https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561199093445177
avatar => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/87/8795cc1582c0949615b54bdac3c3c1f7267ec089_full.jpg
trust => Уровень доверия = 0%
registerdate => Аккаунт создан: 25.09.2020
firstcs => Играет в CS:GO с: 25.09.2020
cshours => Всего часов в CS:GO: 1080.2
lastweekhours => Часов CS:GO за 2 недели: 6.3
achhack => Достижения CS:GO: Не взломаны
matches => Матчей: 36
elo => ELO: 790
kd => K/D: 1.32
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне лично всегда больше нравилось как форматирует json, получше чем pprint. Дело вкуса.

```
from json import dumps

info = [{'name': 'mouse.', 'faceitname': 'ya_lublu_sir', 'link': 'https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561199093445177', 'avatar': 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/87/8795cc1582c0949615b54bdac3c3c1f7267ec089_full.jpg', 'trust': 'Уровень доверия = 0%', 'registerdate': 'Аккаунт создан: 25.09.2020', 'firstcs': 'Играет в CS:GO с: 25.09.2020', 'cshours': 'Всего часов в CS:GO: 1080.2', 'lastweekhours': 'Часов CS:GO за 2 недели: 6.3', 'achhack': 'Достижения CS:GO: Не взломаны', 'matches': 'Матчей: 36', 'elo': 'ELO: 790', 'kd': 'K/D: 1.32'}]

print(dumps(info, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2))
```

Вывод такой:

```
[
  {
    "name": "mouse.",
    "faceitname": "ya_lublu_sir",
    "link": "https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561199093445177",
    "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/87/8795cc1582c0949615b54bdac3c3c1f7267ec089_full.jpg",
    "trust": "Уровень доверия = 0%",
    "registerdate": "Аккаунт создан: 25.09.2020",
    "firstcs": "Играет в CS:GO с: 25.09.2020",
    "cshours": "Всего часов в CS:GO: 1080.2",
    "lastweekhours": "Часов CS:GO за 2 недели: 6.3",
    "achhack": "Достижения CS:GO: Не взломаны",
    "matches": "Матчей: 36",
    "elo": "ELO: 790",
    "kd": "K/D: 1.32"
  }
]
```